# How to read ip address and password from file and execute ssh command using puppet script

Tags: ssh, puppet

Here I have hardcoded username and password but want read it from file.

Command:

`"/bin/bash -c 'sshpass -p root1234 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@ipaddrs qconf -ah $hostname'"`

Comment: You want to read the credentials from *which* file?  In what context is that command string used?  A [mcve] demonstrating what you do now would be helpful in clarifying what you need.

Comment: its a text file containing username and password, or else can we put this command in .sh file and call from puppet script.?